# Python array extraction

Tags: python, arrays, extract

I am extracting the first two rows of an array `A`. In `x1`, I first used `A[:,]` and then `[0:2,:]`. In `x2`, I immediately used `[0:2,:]`. They are basically the same as shown below. However, I saw someone used `A[:,][0:2,:]` but I really don't know the reason for having `[:,]` first. This seems redundant to me. Is there any specific reason that we use  `A[:,][0:2,:]` rather than  `A[0:2,:]`? Sorry if this question looks so easy.

```
import numpy as np

A =np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])

x1=A[:,][0:2,:]

x2=A[0:2,:]

x1
Out[1]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])

x2
Out[2]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: Well, whoever you saw using `A[:,][0:2,:]` probably shouldn't be doing that as it is indeed redundant.

Answer (score 1):

If you do the following code , you will see the reason for the same behaviour -

```
import numpy as np
A =np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
x1=A[:,]
print(x1)
>> array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
```

This is because in `numpy` , `,` is used as the slicing character , if you do `A[:,1] , it would give the results only from 2nd column (index = 1).

If you want [reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.html)

Comment: So having `[:,]` in `A[:,][0:2,:]` is redundant. Right?

Comment: Yes , I believe so, looks like an unneccessary overhead to me